# How to put scrollView inside another Scrollview

Tags: android, scroll, scrollview

what I have is this:

```
<LinearLayout
<ScrollView
<ImageView
<ScrollView
</LinearLayout>
```

It works fine, now I need to do a kind of parent scroll to the hole layout, and when i do this:

```
<LinearLayout
<ScrollView

   <LinearLayout
   <ScrollView
   <ImageView
   <ScrollView
   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView
</LinearLayout>
```

I get the scroll in the entire layout right, but the inside ones do not work, any help would be grate, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that the scroll views inside were for recyclerview adapters. turns out that widget has its own scroll.